# How to add a new Property with BeanSerializerModifier's changeProperties?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

My Code :

`private class CustomBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier{
    @Override
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config,
           BeanDescription beanDesc,List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties){
           List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanPropertiesToIgnore = new ArrayList<>();
           if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(fieldSettingsMap)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < beanProperties.size(); i++) {
                    BeanPropertyWriter beanPropertyWriter = beanProperties.get(i);
                           ...                  ...`

What i want is to add a new property here say, String identifier = "someValue";
i want this property to be added(with some condition) to the serialized json.

The only constructor of BeanPropertyWriter takes lot of arguments :

```
new BeanPropertyWriter(propDef, member, contextAnnotations, declaredType, ser, typeSer, serType, suppressNulls, suppressableValue)
```

Can i add a new property here at all?
if yes, what are the values i should pass to the constructor here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an easy way but you can try the following

From your code, i see this

```
BeanPropertyWriter beanPropertyWriter = beanProperties.get(i);
```

Create a copy of this beanPropertyWriter by using the copy constructor for the new property(Use the following way, as the original constructor is protected and hence not visible)

```
// Use this to create a copy of the old property, and change name to new name
    BeanPropertyWriter newBeanPropertyWriter = new CustomBeanPropertyWriter(beanPropertyWriter,"newFieldName");

        public class CustomBeanPropertyWriter extends BeanPropertyWriter {
                protected CustomBeanPropertyWriter(BeanPropertyWriter base, String newFieldName) {
                    super(base, new SerializedString(newFieldName));
                }
            }
```

This will use the copy constructor to change field Name.

Not sure about the value part but seems that maybe _field holds the same.
Could you check via your debugger which field the value comes and change it accordingly.
Say for example if  _field holds the value then maybe this might work ?

```
public class CustomBeanPropertyWriter extends BeanPropertyWriter {

        protected Field setField(Field newValue){
            super._field = newValue;
        }

        protected CustomBeanPropertyWriter(BeanPropertyWriter base, String newFieldName, Field newFieldValue) {
            super(base, new SerializedString(newFieldName));
            setField(newFieldValue);
        }
    }
```