# How to avoid duplicating JSON field when serializing two fields in one custom Jackson JsonSerializer?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

## Main Goal:

I would like to serialize 2 POJO fields from within 1 field's CustomSerializer while avoiding the default serialization of the second field and keeping the POJO as clean as possible.

###### POJO:

```java
public class Entity{

    // The existence of @JsonProperty on either fields does not change the behavior.
    
    @JsonSerialize(using=MySerializer.class)
    @HashTo("hashedKuku")
    private String kuku;

    private String hashedKuku;

    // Public Getters & Setters for both fields

}
```

###### MySerializer:

```java
public class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    // Some code including try-catch clauses omitted for simplicity.

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value);
        final String currentFieldName = gen.getOutputContext().getCurrentName();
        final Field declaredField = gen.getCurrentValue().getClass().getDeclaredField(currentFieldName);
        final HashTo annotation = declaredField.getAnnotation(HashTo.class);
        final String hashFieldName;
        if(annotation!=null && !(hashFieldName=annotation.value()).isEmpty()) {
            // gen.writeStringField(hashFieldName, new Hasher().getHashedValue(value));
            // OR
            serializers.defaultSerializeField(hashFieldName, new Hasher().getHashedValue(value), gen);              
    }

}
```

#### Expected Result:

```json
{
    "kuku": "someValue",
    "hashedKuku": "someHash"
}
```

#### Actual Result:

```json
{
    "kuku": "someValue",
    "hashedKuku": "someHash",
    "hashedKuku": null
}
```

### The Problem:

`MySerializer` does the job, **and** the defualt serializer serializes `hashedKuku` as well.

#### Constraints:

- `MySeializer` should be on the field itself and **not** a class-level serializer.
- Keep the POJO as clean as possible (have only 2 annotations on `kuku` field).

##### What I've Tried: (Solutions that work but are not good enough)

1. Using `JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY`:

```java
  @JsonProperty(JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  private String hashedKuku;
```

2. Using `@JsonIgnore` on the field:

```java
  @JsonIgnore
  private String hashedKuku;
```

3. Using `@JsonIgnore` on the getter:

```java
  @JsonIgnore
  public String getHashedKuku() {
    return hashedKuku;
  }
```

4. Many more solutions that I will skip as they're either an overengineering or also not good enough.

### Ultimate Solution:

###### Register the serialization of `hashedKuku` so the default serializer skips it.
Maybe get access to the default serializer in `MySerializer` and serialize `hashedKuku` through it?

###### What I've Researched:

- [Jackson add custom field with hash of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849705/jackson-add-custom-field-with-hash-of-another-field?rq=1) - Not good as I have the field in the POJO.
- [Jackson: How to add custom property to the JSON without modifying the POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714328/jackson-how-to-add-custom-property-to-the-json-without-modifying-the-pojo?noredirect=1&lq=1) - Same as first.
- [Jackson add custom field with hash of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849705/jackson-add-custom-field-with-hash-of-another-field) - I do not understand the usage of `BeanSerializerModifier`  or how to register it in a Spring application.
- [How to add a new Property with BeanSerializerModifier's changeProperties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354946/how-to-add-a-new-property-with-beanserializermodifiers-changeproperties)
- [How to access default jackson serialization in a custom serializer with the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944985/how-to-access-default-jackson-serialization-in-a-custom-serializer-with-the-same) - Class-level serializer.
- [Jackson Custom Serializer shows the same context for 2 different field during the Json Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325950/jackson-custom-serializer-shows-the-same-context-for-2-different-field-during-th)
- [Jackson - custom serializer that overrides only specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378853/jackson-custom-serializer-that-overrides-only-specific-fields)
- [How to access default jackson serialization in a custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056215/how-to-access-default-jackson-serialization-in-a-custom-serializer) - Class-level serializer.
- [Jackson custom serializer serialize field twice if property name not equal field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574835/jackson-custom-serializer-serialize-field-twice-if-property-name-not-equal-field)
- [Apply default serializer to properties in custom serializer with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740039/apply-default-serializer-to-properties-in-custom-serializer-with-jackson)
- [Duplicate JSON Field with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237222/duplicate-json-field-with-jackson) - Not same case.
- [Jackson: How to edit existing property to the JSON without modifying the POJO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065614/jackson-how-to-edit-existing-property-to-the-json-without-modifying-the-pojo)

Comment: `@JsonIgnore` should do the trick.

Comment: @talex thanks, I know it does the trick and I am looking for a way that doesn't require me to add anything else but `MySerializer` annotation.